# Создать массив диапазона чисел

Tags: javascript

Нужно создать строку в которой будут числа
12883, 12892-12926

Пока что есть идея создать массив и потом его перевести в строку.
Думал что можно создать массив просто [12883, 12892-12926]
Но ошибся. Как попроще это сделать? "Попроще" в плане минимум кода.
К примеру вариант с циклом не очень нравится. Тогда уже лучше наверное как то .map воспользоватся.

Какие варианты еще?

Comment: сам вопрос: "создать массив", а первое предложение описания: "создать строку". Так что в итоге нужно?)

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, подозреваю вопрос в том, как развернуть запись: `1-4` в `1,2,3,4`

Comment: @Grundy да. верно

Comment: `как развернуть` - в цикле. `вариант с циклом не очень нравится. наверное как то .map воспользоватся` - map, думаешь, не цикл?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  я знаю что это цикл. но мне более приятен и занимает меньше кода и быстрее чем стандартный вариант с фор

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
arr = [12883, ...Array.from(Array(35).keys(),x=>x+12892)]
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
var s = "12883, 12892-12926"

var res = s.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)/g, function (m, l, r) {
  var res = l

  while (++l<=r) {
    res += "," + l
  }

  return res;
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var inputStr = '12-13';

var arr = inputStr.split('-');
var start = +arr[0];
var count = (+arr[1] - arr[0]) + 1;

var result = Array.from(new Array(count),(val,index)=>index + start);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `index + (start)` - зачем тут скобки?

Comment: @Qwertiy да я в начале туда значение массива пихал `+arr[0]`. Потом при переносе в переменные - забыл убрать